# Empty out file on different PCs C#.NET Add-in Outlook

Tags: c#, excel, email, outlook

I have the next problem. I've written the solution for MS Outlook 2010 that creates email summary and write it down to an Excel file(.xls) The problem is that on my PC and several others it works correctly but when I sent it to customers, they said that it creates summary only for inbox folder on some PCs and on others it doesn't work at all.
I've also created the possibility to choose the folder to get the emails but the problem left. I'll provide a code snippet of the function choosing folder and getting the list of emails. I save emails in List in private field of my class.
Take a look on this func and please help to get out what is wrong. Thanks.

```
    public void GetTheArrayOfEmails(DateTime startDate, DateTime finishDate)
    {
        try
        {
            Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.NameSpace oNs = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");
            oNs.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, false);

            //Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = oApp.Session.PickFolder();

            foreach (Outlook.MailItem oMsg in oApp.Session.PickFolder().Items)
            {
                if (oMsg.ReceivedTime.ToUniversalTime() > startDate.ToUniversalTime() &&
                    oMsg.ReceivedTime.ToUniversalTime() < finishDate.ToUniversalTime())
                {
                    MailList.Add(oMsg);
                }
            }
            oNs.Logoff();

            releaseObject(oNs);
            releaseObject(oApp);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

UPD: Fixed the problem. I missed cast. And tried to cast items which are not of MailItem interface.

Comment: BTW, if this is an add-in then there is no need to create a new instance of an Outlook.Application object, as using that object would be untrusted. Use the object provided from Globals.Application (if this is a VSTO project).

Comment: Eric, may be I missed something, but I think by creating oApp in my code I haven't instantiated a new instance of that. I understood the use of interface in this case as simple binding to the already existing object. If I wrong - tell me please)

Comment: It's an "untrusted" instance.  You have to derive all Application objects from the one passed to the add-in via the AddinInitialize event; in this case the VSTO framework manages that for you and stores it in Globals.Application.